# Count If Formula for 2 Separate Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I am trying to write a CountIf Excel formula for 2 separate criteria on the same range. The range consists of a formula that generates a 1 or 2, so the Countif formula tells the user what category that range is. The formula works when it is only for one criteria but I can't get it to work when I add the second CountIf. I appreciate you taking time to read my post. Please let me know if you have any suggestions, thank you!

1 criteria which works `=IF(COUNTIF(M14:AR14,"*"&"1"&"*"),"Check","x")`

2 criteria `=IF(COUNTIF(M14:AR14,"*"&"1"&"*"),"Check",IF(COUNTIF(M14:AR14,"*"&"4"&"*"),"Clear","x"))`

Comment: If there is 1 `1` in the range it will always return `Check`.  It will only return `Clear` if `1` is no where in the range and `4` is at least in one cell in the range.  is that what you have or want?

Comment: What isn't working? If I add x1x to the range, I get  "Check", if I add x4x I get "Clear", without them I get "x". Seems to work?

Comment: Hello All, thank you for your input. When the formula in the range returns a 4, the 2 criteria CountIf gives me a "Check" still. I am using the CountIf formula and asterisk to hard pull the 4 or 1.

Comment: The formula in range the CountIf column is pulling is as follows. Is my range formula not written right? Could that be why I am not getting the "Clear"?

IF(Transactions1[@[Date]]="","",IF(S$11=ATransactions[@[End Date]],4,IF(ISNA(MATCH(S$11,Official_Holiday,0)),IF(OR(WEEKDAY(S$11)=7,WEEKDAY(S$11)=1),2,IF(AND(S$11>=$B14,S$11<=$E14),"1","")),3)))

Comment: Four or so lines of sample data with expected results would probably go a long way to helping out.  Could easily be typed.  If formatting looks off in the end we can probably adjust the formatting for you.  Currently a lot of guessing as to what happens for various cases.

Comment: Thank you all. I figured it out from another forum which suggested just using the number '4' and '1' and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this statement

> When the formula in the range returns a 4, the 2 criteria CountIf gives me a "Check" still.

You have to use :

`=IF(COUNTIF(M14:AR14,"*"&"4"&"*"),"Clear",IF(COUNTIF(M14:AR14,"*"&"1"&"*"),"Check","x"))`

Idea : Need to evaluate whether 4 is present first, then only check for 1.

---

Basically, you need to define the results for the all situations :

- only 1 is present -> 'Check'
- only 4 is present -> 'Clear'
- 1&4 is both absent -> 'x'
- both 1&4 is present -> (output) '?'

Then we sequence the inner/outer IF() conditions.

Hope it helps. ( :

Comment: The problem was solved by just using '4' and '1'. Thank you for your tip however. It makes a lot of sense and I changed my logic accordingly. 

IF(COUNTIF(M12:AR12,4),"Clear",IF(COUNTIF(M12:AR12,1),"Check","x"))